# Cache models in Promela

Tags: c, multithreading, multicore, spin, promela

I am looking to model cache for multicore processors, including cache coherence. Do such PROMELA implementations already exist. I tried to search for it, but couldn't find any. Secondly, if I have to implement it myself, is it feasible in PROMELA to declare very large arrays as in to represent cache structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally don't know of such existing Promela models. Moreover, large array structures sounds like a serious state blow-up.

Depending on what properties you want to show, I would suggest to abstract from reality as much as possible. Modeling things with a high precision compared to the real world is typically nothing one should do in Promela.

Two alternative suggestions:

- Model your cache in Java and prove first-order assertions with the [KeY proof system](http://www.key-project.org/)
- Model your cache in a mathematical fashion using the [Coq proof assistant](http://coq.inria.fr/) and prove the desired theorems with Coq

Answer (score 1):

[This is the type of question that would be closed… but there aren't many people answering Promela/SPIN questions so you won't get 5 close votes.]

[Google Search for 'formal verification cache coherence spin'](http://bit.ly/1dkofwb) notes SPIN use a couple of times.

There is a yearly [SPIN Workshop](http://spinroot.com/spin/Workshops/); full papers are listed for the last 14 years.